# Icon badge counter is not working properly, Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, counter, badge

I am working with badge icon /shopping cart icon counter.
Counter ++ code is working properly while adding items in cart.
but when removing item , counter -- is not working properly.

```
//increment in badge icon number when new item added in cart
                      var counter = parseInt($(".badge").html()) + 1;
                        $(".badge").html(counter);

//decrement in badge icon number when item removed from cart
                  var counter = parseInt($(".badge").html()) - 1;
                        $(".badge").html(counter);

//html code
<li class="icon-link"><a href="#" id="cart-icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><span class="badge cart-badge">0</span></i></a></li>
```

Comment: Kindly share your html too

Comment: I edited the code.. see now

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(".badge").html(counter);` instead of `temp.html(counter);`.

Because, temp will be holding the value of badge.

```js
$('.increase').on('click', function() {
  var temp = $(".badge").html();
  var counter = parseInt(temp) + 1;
  $(".badge").html(counter);
})

$('.decrease').on('click', function() {
  var temp = $(".badge").html();
  var counter = parseInt(temp) - 1;
  $(".badge").html(counter);
})
```

```css
.badge {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="icon-link"><a href="#" id="cart-icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><span class="badge cart-badge">0</span></i></a></li>

<button class='increase'>Icrease</button>
<button class='decrease'>Icrease</button>
```

EDIT

Added the increase and decrease functionalities.

Comment: I tried $(".badge").html(counter); still not working

Comment: Increment counter is working properly.. Problem is with decrement counter.. I cant figure out it because code is the same only difference is ++ and -- !!!!

Comment: @SafinaSiddique,... Edited the answer with increase and decrease

Comment: I wrote click function on remove item in a click function of addToCart button. and everytime i add item to cart inner click function stores those calls for remove item function and that many times decrease cart badge value upon one click.. I am unable to find solution.

Comment: Are your issues fixed ? @SafinaSiddique

Comment: Yes .. I wrote click function ouside the other click function and it got resolved.